# Capture in real-time pages visted by user

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-internet

I want to make small parental control application. It should capture URLs of all visited by user pages and save it to the log-file. I do not know how to do that, because user can use any available web-browser and that is simply impossible to my app is coworking with everything. I tried to do read about capturing hole network traffic, but that requries root permissions. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It seems that something like this already exists. http://kidlogger.net/kidlogger-android-features.html

Comment: Yes, it seems, but I want to create my own solution and additionally this app gathers info only from Android Browser and Chrome.